# xml to html out using xslt stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert a xml file using xslt stylesheet to html format for printing out values.
my .xml files looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type= "text/xsl" href="rt.xsl"?>
<entityset>    
<entity id="32" name="RT: Testing : Testing" hidden="true">
    <attribute id="1242" name="Tiketi receiver" code="start_supportGroup">
        <value>3.Saldo</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="682" name="Kohde" code="store">
        <reference id="288799" name="Market"/>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="683" name="Contact" code="person">
        <value>john.doe@market.com</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="684" name="Puhelinnumero" code="phone">
        <value>0505444566</value>
    </attribute>
</entity>
<entity id="32" name="RT: Testing2 : Testing2" hidden="true">
    <attribute id="1243" name="Tiketi receiver2" code="start_supportGroup">
        <value>4.Saldo</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="682" name="Kohde" code="store">
        <reference id="288799" name="Market2"/>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="683" name="Contact" code="person">
        <value>john.doe2@market.com</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="684" name="Puhelinnumero" code="phone">
        <value>05054445663</value>
    </attribute>
</entity>
</entityset>
```

And I would like to print out an html td elements for the code="" part in the attribute.
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="entity">
<html>
<body>
<h2>RKPP-TIKETIT</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">ID</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Kohde</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">StartSupportgroup</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="entity/attribute">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:for-each select="attribute">
  <xsl:attribute name="{@code}" >
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:for-each></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hi can I achieve this please advice.

EDIT: this is what I wanna achieve:

```
start_supportgroup  store   phone
<td>3.Saldo</td>    <td>Market</td>     <td>505444566</td>
<td>4.Saldo</td>    <td>Market2</td>    <td>5054445663</td>
```

as image:
http://www.imgrobot.com/image/wUQ

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Hi, yes I have. How do I print out using html table td values of the <attribute id="1243" name="Tiketi receiver2" code="start_supportGroup">
        <value>4.Saldo</value>

Comment: Original question edited with wanted output

Comment: Your wanted output does not match your XSLT. And your input sample is not well-formed. Please fix both of these things. Be precise, hand-waving benefits no-one.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to output `attribute` elements whose code="start_supportGroup"?

Comment: Hi, I want to output all attribute codes, store, phone, person and also the <reference name"Market">

Comment: Tomalak sorry the output was just an example.. the wanted output is found after the EDIT text.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't quite follow. Please post the **full output** you expect from the given example.

Comment: Hi Michael added and image for wanted output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/entityset">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>StartSupportgroup</th>
            <th>Store</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entity"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entity">  
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="attribute[@code='start_supportGroup']/value"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="attribute[@code='store']/reference/@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="attribute[@code='phone']/value"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input, this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>StartSupportgroup</th>
      <th>Store</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3.Saldo</td>
      <td>Market</td>
      <td>0505444566</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4.Saldo</td>
      <td>Market2</td>
      <td>05054445663</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael yes this is exactly what I wanted.. the for each part is missing can you write this also?

Comment: @user2023042 The for-each part is not "missing". It is *eliminated* by using templates instead.

Comment: True.. for some reason its not changing the rows and it looks like this in IE http://www.imgrobot.com/images/2014/10/31/output2.jpg

Comment: How can we fix so it prints a real nice table in IE? Points coming your way

Comment: @user2023042 Not sure what you mean "a real nice table". You can add CSS styles to the table (similar to what you had in your XSLT). That's not relevant to your question and I have no interest in doing that.

Comment: No what I meant was the output you showed in your example.. for some reason I'm not getting any row changes in my output but in your output there is an actual table, anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user2023042 I really don't know. Did you get a table before, using your own stylesheet? Perhaps you need to add the <html> and <body> wrappers.

Comment: @user2023042 Then you must have done something wrong. See if this version works for you: http://pastebin.com/caQKgiiK

Comment: Thanks, it was IE 11 when I set it to IE 9 mode it works thanksr for you superb effort and help